# Sitecore caching issues on mobile ( Ipad- I phone)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have an issue with Sitecore in mobile device, new styles are not effective. 
I am trying to clear site cache, but a new file still not responsive on mobile.

Comment: Are you using HTTP Cache Headers?

Comment: No,I am not using HTTP Cache Headers

Comment: your question is not very clear, but do you mean that a .css file is cached in a mobile browser? it is common to have a build nummer in the filename or querystring to prevent serving an old one.